# meta_query dates from an array

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, mysql

I have the below query which isn't returning anything. The query is meant to look for the date (2014-03-01) that is in the array, which it is.

Any ideas? Or would I need to use a custom SQL query?

```
// the income_dates array looks like this
// a:3:{i:0;s:10:"2014-02-01";i:1;s:10:"2014-03-01";i:2;s:10:"2014-03-29";}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'income',
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
            'key' => 'income_dates',
            'value' => "2014-02-01",
            'type'  => 'date',
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Do you want to use the complete array in the `meta_query` or just a single element from the array as above?

Comment: Just a single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the meta as a serialized array, you should do meta query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'income',
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
            'key' => 'income_dates',
            'value' => "2014-02-01",
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    )
);
```